# How to prevent a nichrome wire from melting under variable energy?

Tags: resistors, solar-cell, solar-energy, diy

I’m experimenting with a DIY “sand battery”.

[image: DIY Sand Battery]

The “battery” is a pot lined inside with an insulator and filled with sand. The sand is heated by a nichrome wire placed at the bottom. The wire is connected DIRECTLY to my solar panels (two 160 W panels) and a thermometer measures the inner temperature. I found through trial and error that:

- If I make the wire too short, the wire will melt and the circuit will break
- If I make the wire too long or too thick, it won't glow and the amount of heat it delivers falls, as proven by the fact that the temperature of the battery doesn't rise much
- If I make the wire just long enough, it will glow and the the temperature of the battery will rise nicely

However, the problem is that the amount of energy that the sun delivers is variable. If I size the wire for summer, then during the winter it won't glow or heat much. If I size it for winter, then during the summer it will melt and break.

Is there some way around this? Some trick, some material, some arrangement? Or is it just not possible?

Comment: Measure the current best fit to your magic pot and maintain it with current limiter (linear or switched).